# pocket ie renders carriage returns in html?

Tags: newline, html-rendering, pocket-ie, windows-mobile

We're writing a series of screens designed to be used on Pocket IE, on a batch of handheld scanner units from Motorola (aka Symbol). As is typical, I am trying to layout my HTML in something of a readable format, which new controls on new lines, instead of just running my code all together into one big giant unreadable mess.

Here is an example of my problem though. I have a series of asp:linkbuttons, which are supposed to render each on a new line. In my code I put each <asp:linkbutton> tag on a new line. Pocket IE however is actually RENDERING the CrLf in the code file into the output, putting a giant space between the rendered A tags which I cannot control.

Is there some directive I can put in the page to stop pIE from rendering the hard CrLfs that I put in my code? If I want a new line I want to just put in a BR tag, not have it actually render CrLfs from the codefile.

The devices are running WinMo 6.1.

Comment: Well, I worked around it by putting the linkbuttons in a table... I was TRYING to not use tables and do it using modern CSS layouts, but apparently that's not going to happen.

Comment: Well, stupid IE rendering ... if i wrap each linkbutton in a div tag on its own line, then it does NOT render the linebreaks. Who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped each of the linkbuttons in a div, and then it rendered without the linebreaks.